# Add prometheus ready application to the Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a python application installed on the `default` namespace of the Kubernetes service. It uses `starlette_exporter` and exposes `/metrics` endpoint to Prometheus. When I access `1.2.3.4/metrics` endpoint I see:

```
...
process_open_fds 21.0
# HELP process_max_fds Maximum number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_max_fds gauge
process_max_fds 1.048576e+06
# HELP starlette_request_duration_seconds HTTP request duration, in seconds
# TYPE starlette_request_duration_seconds histogram  
starlette_request_duration_seconds_bucket{app_name="starlette",le="0.005",method="GET",path="/sitemap.xml",status_code="404"} 1.0
starlette_request_duration_seconds_bucket{app_name="starlette",le="0.01",method="GET",path="/sitemap.xml",status_code="404"} 1.0
starlette_request_duration_seconds_bucket{app_name="starlette",le="0.025",method="GET",path="/sitemap.xml",status_code="404"} 1.0
...
```

I also installed `kube-prometheus-stack` on the `monitor` namespace of that Kubernetes service. It has no customizations and I used this command for installation:

```
helm install prometheus-stack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitor
```

What are the necessary steps to add my application metrics to the Prometheus stack that I can track them on the Grafana dashboard? As I understand, I should write a custom configuration and somehow include that in Prometheus probably by issuing some kind of `kubectl` command. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create service monitor in the namespace in application namespace for your application so that prometheus can read it and configure the scrape job. you can refer below snippet.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    release: prometheus-operator
  name: keycloak
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 60s
    path: /auth/realms/master/metrics
    port: http
    scrapeTimeout: 30s
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: keycloak
      app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak
      service: http
```

you can refer [this](https://coreos.com/blog/the-prometheus-operator.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

"Navigate to your prometheus.yml file in the prometheus directory, and add in the IP to the targets field. [See their docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/) and example below

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

...
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['1.2.3.4:9090']
```

The targets example uses port 9090 by default, but replace that with whatever port you personally have exposing metrics to prometheus.
The next step is to install grafana in the same root directory as the base of your prometheus folder. Install it and launch it on port 3000 with username/password of "admin". From this point, I [recommend just following their documentation step by step.](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/getting-started/getting-started/) You can manually add your own grafana panel, and just typing in the desired metric name a graph should appear automatically.